# Встроенное видео(Youtube) тормозит загрузку сайта

Tags: веб-программирование

Имеется сайт(обычный лэндинг, Bootstrap). В определенном блоке подключено видео с Ютуба

```
<iframe width="300" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Всё бы хорошо, да только тупнячек происходит, пока коннектимся к гуглу/ютубу. Причем это происходит в порядке загрузки страницы.
Ставил прелоадер - слишком долго висит, я бы закрыл нафиг такой сайт сразу.
Возможно что то придумать, что бы некоторые... тэги я не знаю, "отвести" на последнюю очередь в загрузке страницы? Или как быть?
Спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Могу сказать, как я делал для сайта нашей последней игры http://en.unnyworld.com/

1. На странице размещаем картинку.
2. Делаем похожей на то, что показывается при вставке видео и т.п.
3. И только по клику на картинку вызываем загрузку видео.

При таком решение загрузка страницы вообще тормозиться не будет.

Comment: Я понял! А это идея! Спасибо!

Comment: @AIex рад помочь (;

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно добавить в дом по событию после загрузки страницы:

1. DOMContentLoaded - после загрузки всех элементов DOM
2. window.onload - после полной загрузки всего контента страницы

Либо можешь спрятать видео в какое-нибудь модальное окно и загружать его при вызове модали.

Comment: Что значит спрятать? Если видео не видно, это не означает что оно не будет загружаться (фрейм). Можно попробовать немного по другому вставлять пустой фрейм с меткой youtube <iframe data-src="url видео" data-youtube=""> после загрузки страницы (Дом дерева, документа), менять iframe.src на data-src и только тогда По идее должна начаться загрузка

Comment: Да, примерно это я и имел ввиду.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на чистом JavaScript, работает в современных браузерах, ну и в IE11 тоже:

```js
let buttonPlay = document.querySelector('button');
buttonPlay.onclick = function() {
  this.parentElement.innerHTML = '<div>Тут будет iframe</div>';
};
```

```html
<center>
  <div style="width:100px;height:100px;box-sizing:border-box;padding-top:35px;border:1px solid">
    <button>Play</button>
  </div>
</center>
```

Посмотрите полную реализацию тут: https://jsfiddle.net/ped3hL9f/1/

Answer (score 0):

Была схожая проблема, слайдер с ютубовскими видео. Сделал так, что бы iframe'ы загружались только если они видны в окне браузера. Естественно, если iframe находится на первом блоке, это не поможет. Таким образом изначально сайт загрузится без iframe, а когда мы к ним доскролим - они загрузятся. Так же есть проверка, если изначально блок виден (т.е если перезагрузим страницу на этом блоке, то они сразу грузится будут) . Это решило мою проблему.

```js
// Получаем нужный элемент
  var element = document.querySelector('#video');

  var Visible = function (target) {
    // Все позиции элемента
    var targetPosition = {
        top: window.pageYOffset + target.getBoundingClientRect().top,
        left: window.pageXOffset + target.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        right: window.pageXOffset + target.getBoundingClientRect().right,
        bottom: window.pageYOffset + target.getBoundingClientRect().bottom,
      },
      // Получаем позиции окна
      windowPosition = {
        top: window.pageYOffset,
        left: window.pageXOffset,
        right: window.pageXOffset + document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        bottom: window.pageYOffset + document.documentElement.clientHeight,
      };

    if (
      // Если позиция нижней части элемента больше позиции верхней чайти окна, то элемент виден сверху
      targetPosition.bottom > windowPosition.top &&
      // Если позиция верхней части элемента меньше позиции нижней чайти окна, то элемент виден снизу
      targetPosition.top < windowPosition.bottom &&
      targetPosition.right > windowPosition.left &&
      // Если позиция правой стороны элемента больше позиции левой части окна, то элемент виден слева
      targetPosition.left < windowPosition.right
    ) {
      // Если позиция левой стороны элемента меньше позиции правой чайти окна, то элемент виден справа
      // Если элемент полностью видно, то запускаем следующий код
      $('.video__item iframe').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('src').length == 0) {
          let srcVideo = $(this).attr('data-src');
          $(this).attr('src', srcVideo);
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
    } else {
      // Если элемент не видно, то запускаем этот код
      return false;
    }
  };

  // Запускаем функцию при прокрутке страницы
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    Visible(element);
  });

  // А также запустим функцию сразу. А то вдруг, элемент изначально видно
  Visible(element);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe
    width="1280"
    height="700"
    data-src="Код  из ссылка iframe youtube"
    src=""
    title="20 августа 2023 г."
    frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; 
gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
    allowfullscreen
  ></iframe>
```